# Scala: printing a DateTime object in specific format

Tags: scala

I have a DateTime object and I want to print it with a given format, let's say `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I've tried

```
val date = DateTime.now()
val format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
println(date.formatted(format))
```

but got `yyyy-MM-dd` as if the format wasn't recognized.

I also tried

```
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format)
println(
```

but got

> Cannot format given Object as a Date
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

**How do I print the DateTime object in the format of my choosing?**

Comment: is it a joda DateTime?

Comment: if so, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331163/how-to-format-joda-time-datetime-to-only-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format Joda-Time DateTime to only mm/dd/yyyy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331163/how-to-format-joda-time-datetime-to-only-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: @pedrorijo91 although the answers overlap, the PO in that question asks about parsing a string, not a DateTime object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a date object has a `toString(format: String)` method.

```
date.toString(format)
```

> 2017-05-07