# How to convert the dd/mm/yyyy to yyyymmdd in scala by using joda time

Tags: scala, jodatime

How can I convert the dd/mm/yyyy to **yyyymmdd** format and also
**dd/m/yyyy** to **yyyymmdd** format by using **joda time** in Scala.

am using this dependency

```
 "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9",
```

Comment: Any good reason not to use `java.time`?

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331163/how-to-format-joda-time-datetime-to-only-mm-dd-yyyy) already answers your question in Java, but here it is translated into Scala:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.{DateTimeFormat, DateTimeFormatter}

// define original date format
val originalFormat: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
val input: DateTime = originalFormat.parseDateTime("02/09/2017")

// define new format
val newFormat: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
val output: String = newFormat.print(input) // 20170902
```

This code will already account for missing a leading `0` from your date (ie it will see `02/9/2017` and `2/9/2017` as the same thing). It will not predict missing parts of the year though, so `2/9/17` will be outputted as `00170902` instead of `20170902`.

As the answer I linked to earlier mentions though, you can just use `java.time` to do the same thing:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val originalFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
val input = LocalDate.parse("02/09/2017", originalFormat)
val newFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
val output = input.format(newFormat)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format._

val fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/mm/yyyy")
val dt = fmt.parseDateTime("02/02/2017")
val fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyymmdd")
fmt2.print(dt)
```

Comment: Wrong patterns! Use "MM", not "mm".

Comment: I was just using the same patterns I see on the question.

Comment: Wrong pattern MM not mm