# Convert a date of 6 months ago from now, into a String

Tags: java, date, format, jodatime, simpledateformat

I've taken all of the answers given on SOF and other websites and tried to do this:

```
String fromDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssX").format(new DateTime().plusMonths(-6));
```

But I'm being given the exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What `DateTime` class is it you're using?

Comment: Using Joda-Time? Then just stick to it and use its formatter too (not `SimpleDateFormat`, it’s notoriously troublesome, and Joda-Time has got a replacement). Alternatively skip both and use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) entirely.

Comment: Or use the new java date time classes: `ZonedDateTime.now().minusMonths(6).toString()`.

Comment: @Arnaud That was indeed the problem. A toDate made it right. The actual problem was I had no compilation errors whatsoever. Kinda strange, since there is no connection between Date and DateTime (polymorphism). I wonder how it couldn't give me any tips or even errors.

Comment: @Marco `Date` and `DateTime` are from unrelated frameworks, so no polymorphic relationship. Just the opposite, the second is from Joda-Time (apparently) and was intended to *replace* the first not supplement. The creator of Joda-Time went on to create its successor, JSR 310 and the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. So no reason to ever again touch the terrible wretched awful `Date` and `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. Use only classes from the *java.time* package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### java.time

```
    String fromDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusMonths(6).toString();
    System.out.println(fromDateTime);
```

Output when running on my computer just now:

> 2018-08-04T12:45:34.087966+01:00

java.time is the modern Java date and time API and has effectively replaced Joda-Time. From the home page:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to `java.time` (JSR-310).

In the code I am taking advantage of the fact that the java.time classes’ `toString` methods produce ISO 8601 format, the format you were asking for. I find it unlikely that the extra decimals on the seconds will pose any problem since thay are allowed within the standard.

### Joda-Time

```
    String fromDateTime = new DateTime().minusMonths(6).toString();
```

Example output:

> 2018-08-04T12:50:36.071+02:00

`new DateTime()` only has millisecond precision. You will always get exactly 3 decimals on the seconds.

### I gotta use old java libraries, cause I work for a company that uses java version < 8

java.time works nicely on Java 6 and 7 too, and all things being equal I recommend it over Joda-Time. Only if forced to use Java 5, Joda-Time is no doubt the good choice.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) java.time comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### What went wrong in your code?

Your code can be compiled without signs of errors, but issues a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date` when run. This is because a `SimpleDateFormat` cannot format a Joda-Time `DateTime` object. We would of course have expected this to be reported on compile time. But in addition to `SimpleDateFormat.format(Date)` there is also an overridden `format(Object)` inherited from `Format`. It works for formatting either a `Date` or a `Number` (for milliseconds since the epoch). This method is the one that the compiler chooses when you pass a `DateTime`. Which is why there is no compile-time error message.

Tip: When you don’t immediately understand an error message, paste it into your search engine. It will very often lead you to an explanation and a solution. Also in this case.

### Links

- [Joda-Time home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Sister question: Java : Cannot format given Object as a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649782/java-cannot-format-given-object-as-a-date).

Comment: You couldn't be any more specific in ALL aspects. Thank you man, you actually taught me a lot! You just deserved the green check.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
String fromDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssX").format(new DateTime().minusMonths(6).toDate());
```

You have to convert the `DateTime` to a `Date` before formatting, using the `toDate()` method will do the job.

[API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate()) for `toDate()` and [API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusMonths(int)) for `minusMonths`, I would recommend to you check the API for new methods

Comment: Will work, but not the recommended way. You are going from the good library (Joda-Time) into the bad one (`Date`and `SimpleDateFormat`).

Comment: this indeed solved my problem. But I wonder: you talk about good and bad libraries. What's the point, if eventually I get things working fine?

Comment: for some scenarios you may have incompatibility problems using multiple libraries, wrong conversion, etc...

Comment: @ngueno Yeah you're right, but in my scenario I see no problems at all :p Thanks everybody for your (date_) time!

Comment: On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331163/how-to-format-joda-time-datetime-to-only-mm-dd-yyyy) answer you may find some other examples using other libraries.

Comment: @Marco SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe. Joda and Java 8 libraries give you thread-safe formatters. It's never recommended to mix different libraries, but using the old Java date-related classes is really to be avoided.

Comment: I gotta use old java libraries, cause I work for a company that uses java version < 8

Comment: You should consider rewriting the formatter using [Joda DateTimeFormatter](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), which is thread safe and available in the Joda package

Comment: Ok, I'll do. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The problem with using multiple libraries and/or a bad library is for those maintaining your code. Using two libraries renders the code unnecessarily complex (even though we’re talking just one extra method call in this case). Using a troublesome library class is likely to cause trouble if someone wants to modify the code later (which is likely of your program is to last, say, a couple of years).