# How to format DateTime variable in Android

Tags: android, datetime, format

In my project i am using the [HorizontalPicker](https://github.com/jhonnyx2012/HorizontalPicker) third party library for date selection. However i'm struggling to change the format of the DateTime variable when i display the value in a textview.

Output:
[image]

How would i format this to something that is more easier for the user to read to something like "10-May-2020"

Code:

```
@Override
public void onDateSelected(@NonNull final DateTime dateSelected)
{
    displayDate.setText(dateSelected.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Horizontal picker](https://github.com/jhonnyx2012/HorizontalPicker) uses [Joda Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) for date and time. you can use `DateTimeFormatter` for foramt datetime. For more ref read [How to format Joda-Time DateTime to only mm/dd/yyyy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331163/how-to-format-joda-time-datetime-to-only-mm-dd-yyyy)
 answer.

```
@Override
public void onDateSelected(@NonNull final DateTime dateSelected)
{
      DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
      // Printing the date
      System.out.println(dtfOut.print(dateSelected));
//    displayDate.setText(dateSelected.toString());
}
```